# Best datatype for storing html

Tags: c#

I need to store HTML in one of the varibles in my class, which datatype would you suggest? Will string be ok or is there any special datatype I can use for this kind of operation.

Comment: string will be fine

Comment: String is OK, but consider: HtmlString or another type if it is important to distinguish encoded strings from not-encoded ones; StringBuilder if you are building /modifing if to avoid performance issues

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`string` if you're storing the raw HTML.

If you were planning on storing an object-representation of the HTML, then obviously you would use that object.

However, if it's just the raw HTML string, you'd use a `string`. There's nothing specially suited to any type of string content.

*Actually, there kindof is, but it has a specialist usage to represent already-encoded HTML data that should not be encoded again (generally used to output raw HTML in ASP.NET). This isn't what you want, but just so that this answer is complete - [`HtmlString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring.aspx).*